# ipv6 tcp connection fails while ipv4 connection succeeds

Tags: ipv6, tcpclient, ipv4

I have a .Net app that is working perfectly with a remote server (running on various platforms) that listening to port 'port' when connecting using these lines:

```
IPAddress iAddr = IPAddress.Parse(hostIp);
m_clientSocket = new TcpClient(iAddr.AddressFamily);
m_clientSocket.SendTimeout = DEFAULT_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT;
m_clientSocket.Connect(iAddr, (int)port);enter code here
```

when hostIp is of IPv4 type i.e. ddd.ddd.ddd.ddd (ddd is 0-255) it works just fine.
when hostIp is of type IPv6 i.e. hhhh:hhhh:hhhh:hhhh:hhhh:hhhh:hhhh:hhhh a valid IPv6 address (pinged it to make sure it works) I get the following exception :

```
No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
```

what do I miss here? any configuration should be made on the remote host?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure the target machines listens on both IPv4 and IPv6?

Comment: yap  
Pinging <ipv6 address > with 32 bytes of data:  
Reply from <ipv6 address > time<1ms  
Reply from <ipv6 address > time<1ms  
Reply from <ipv6 address > time<1ms  
Reply from <ipv6 address > time<1ms  

Ping statistics for <ipv6 address >:  
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),  
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:  
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Average = 0ms

Comment: sorry about the bad format. Just wanted to show the output of the ping. that means the machine listens to IPv6, isn't it?

Comment: Answering to ping is not the same as listening on a certain socket. You could try to connect to the socket with telnet, or if you have access to the machine, use netstat to show the ports that are listening.

Comment: What @KarstenKoop said. Also see [What causes the 'Connection Refused' message?](https://serverfault.com/q/725262/126632) on [sf] for a detailed explanation of the reasons why this happens.